# Why is `csrf_exempt` not needed when using django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, csrf, django-csrf

When I make a POST request with Postman, I receive an error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`

```
class BooksView(View):
    def post(self, request):
```

If I use `csrf_exempt` the error does not occur

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class BooksView(View):
    def post(self, request):
```

However, this error does not occur at all when I use `django-rest-framework`

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

# /books
class BooksView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
```

What is [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and the `APIView` class doing in relation to `csrf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All views and viewsets in django-rest-framework inherit from `APIView`, this class wraps itself with `csrf_exempt` [in the `as_view` method](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L144).